# IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender): Is this syntactic sugar?

Tags: c#, .net, ideserializationcallback

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx), an example of using the `IDeserializationCallback` interface.

```
void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender) 
{
    // After being deserialized, initialize the m_area field 
    // using the deserialized m_radius value.
    m_area = Math.PI * m_radius * m_radius;
}
```

But this method signature doesn't look familiar to me. The `.` notation makes me think there is something "tricky" going on here.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [explicit implementation of interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Ah ha. I should have known that!  :-)

Comment: well not really, if you mostly work on business applications of small to medium scale, you will rarely see such things.

Comment: The main purpose here is to hide the interface methods unless the object is cast to that specific interface. You need to do it if you are implementing multiple interfaces with the same method name (and they need to do different stuff).